# Flaw within my method ? I know there is some subtle error but what exactly is it?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Question: A pair of fair dice is thrown. Find the probability $p$ that
>   the sum is $10$ or greater, if $5$ appears on at least one die?

First solution:
Sample space is reduced to
$$S=\left\{(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(5,6),(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(6,5)\right\}$$
The entries such that the sum is greater than or equal to ten are $(5,5),(5,6),(6,5)$
Therefore $3/11$ should be the required probability.
This is clearly the correct solution.

Second solution:
Let $a$ be the reading on first die and $b$ be the reading on second die.
So, the condition can be "partitioned" into two cases:

1. $a=5$ has happened and $b\ge5$
2. $b=5$ has happened and $a>5$
3. $P(b\ge5|a=5)= (2/36)/(6/36) = 1/3$
4. $P(a>5|b=5)= (1/36)/(6/36) = 1/6$

Therefore the required probability is $= 1/3 + 1/6 = 1/2$

This method is clearly wrong. I think that I shouldn't use the word partition, but I am not able to make out why I am wrong. Please help I have been struggling for two hours.

Comment: Please try and use MathJax formatting next time.

Comment: Thank u, I will

Comment: @nbubis do you by any chance understand where I'm wrong??

Comment: The problem is that you can't add $P(A|B)$ and $P(C|D)$. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Instead you should take $P(b\ge 5 \text{ and } a=5 | a=5 \text{ or } b=5)$ and $P(a> 5 \text{ and } b=5 | a=5 \text{ or } b=5)$ and add these

Comment: I mean what do you think adding those things ought to be? It's fuzzy, because it's not clear what it means. It's not $P(A\text{ or } C| B\text{ or }D)$. The problem is $P(A|B)$ and $P(C|D)$ are probabilities coming from different probability spaces.

Comment: Ohhh you are right. It was a blunder on my part to add the two. Thank you. I can't add measures that are simply not on the same space. Really thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, writing out the sample space and event space is the easiest approach. However, if you do want to use Bayes' theorem (good practice since writing out all the possibilities isn't always practical) then $P(b\geq5|a=5)$ is not what you want. Those events are independent of each other. What you do want is

$$\begin{align*}
P(a+b\geq10 | a=5 \cup b=5)
&= \frac{P(a+b \geq 10 \cap (a=5 \cup b=5))}{P(a=5 \cup b=5)}\\\\
&=\frac{P((a=5 \cup b=5)| a+b\geq 10)\cdot P(a+b \geq 10)}{P(a=5 \cup b=5)}\\\\
&= \frac{\frac{3}{6}\cdot\frac{6}{36}}{\frac{11}{36}} \\\\
&= \frac{3}{11}\\\\
& \approx .273
\end{align*}$$

Or more simply,

$$\begin{align*}
P(a+b\geq10 | a=5 \cup b=5)
&= \frac{P(a+b \geq 10 \cap (a=5 \cup b=5))}{P(a=5 \cup b=5)}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{3}{36}}{\frac{11}{36}}\\\\
&= \frac{3}{11}\\\\
& \approx .273
\end{align*}$$